# SQL Column Data Comparison to File Name

Tags: c#, sql, fileinfo

I have data in an SQL table:

```
name      | size
database  | 100
database2 | 50
database3 | 300
```

and I have matching backup files of these data bases:

```
database_20110307.bak
database2_20110307.bak
database3_20110307.bak
```

Essentially what I need to do is load the file, compare the file name to make sure the sql name matches the file name, then see if the size of the file is equal to the file size stored in sql.

Currently I've loaded the entire sql database in an html string so that its contents can be emailed to myself. I don't know how to begin doing the aforementioned comparison.

Here's how I created the string, if this helps:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{
    if (!myReader.IsDBNull(i))
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2)
            emailMessage += "<td>" + myReader.GetString(i) + "</td>";
        else if (i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 5)
            emailMessage += "<td>" + myReader.GetDateTime(i).ToString() +"</td>";
        else if (i == 6 || i == 7)
            emailMessage += "<td>" + myReader.GetDecimal(i).ToString() + "</td>";
        else
            emailMessage += "<td>" + myReader.GetInt32(i).ToString() + "</td>";
    }
    else
        emailMessage += "<td></td>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load the data containing `databases` and their `size` in `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>` for example. You could then use `FileInfo` to find file size by calling its `Length()` method. You could then search in the List to find the element whose name is equal to the `string` or `substring` of the file name, then you could compare the `size`.